# Eclipse: JBoss + Maven MANIFEST.MF generation by project publishing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I have EJB project with `application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
    version="5">
    <display-name>ejb.project</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>some.prj.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

In `some.prj` project I have dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.FINAL</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>     
</dependency>
```

and plugin for generate MANIFEST:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Dependencies>org.infinispan export</Dependencies>                          
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also I have JBoss AS 7.1 plugin for Eclipse and trying to publish my project to server from IDE (full publish or increment publish doesn't matter), everything works fine except one thing, MANIFEST for project some.prj isn't creating at all.
But if I run `mvn package` for that EJB project it works very fine, I have my MANIFEST there.

**Question:** So, how should I configure JBoss AS plugin or maybe Eclipse for generate that MANIFEST by project publishing?